# Get values from tuple in dict

Tags: python

Good time a day.
I have got python name consist of tuple and list of dict for example

```
value_dict = ({key1: value , key2:value},{key1: value , key2:value} )
```

I want to get some values by using for.
I try to make it with that code:

```
for name_area, area_id in value_dict['area_id'], value_dict['name_area']:
        area.append(name_area[0])
```

But got an error:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: Is `key1` supposed to be `area_id` and `key2` is `area_name`? Also, do you already have an initialized list named `area`?

Comment: try value_dict['area_id']['name_area']   if your dictionaries are nested

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is similar to what you want to achieve, but here it is.

Basically, you tried iterating over those dictionaries in the tuple, which caused the error.

```
# This is just a random example that I generated myself.
locations = (
    {
        "location_id": 1234,
        "location_name": "Spain",
    },
    {
        "location_id": 5678,
        "location_name": "France",
    }
)

areas = [] # Initialize a list if you haven't.

for location in locations:
    areas.append(location["location_name"])
```